# Foursquare venue's category photos issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, foursquare

i am having trouble about json part of venues, in this picture i am trying to take the prefix and suffix,[image]  i am putting size between them but my problem is when i try to put them together the link of prefix + size + suffix comes like this -> [image] i am taking prefix and suffix in seperate NSMutableArray's but when i try to join them together it's not working. and here is my way to join them.[image]

where am i doing this wrong?

Comment: Your problem is in the method that fills `imagePrefix` and `imageSuffix`. Do a `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([imagePrefix objectAtIndex:e]));` and you will see that the object is a NSArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to "Matthias Bauch" i figured it out and here is my answer for my own question :)

```
           for (int e = 0; e<=[imagePrefix count]-1; e++) {
                NSLog(@"%@b_32%@", [[imagePrefix objectAtIndex:e] objectAtIndex:0], [[imageSuffix objectAtIndex:e] objectAtIndex:0]);
            }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your objects in the `imagePrefix` and `imageSuffix` arrays are actually strings? Because judging from your logs it looks as if you're trying to concatenate two arrays and a string. If you let us know what is actually in those arrays you might get more helpful answers. You must be doing some conversion/manipulation from the original JSON, as in the API they get returned as dictionary items not arrays.

On a unrelated note, consider using fast enumeration (`for id item in array`) rather than writing out the for statement as you've done. Generally speaking it's also much better to post your code as text using markdown syntax rather than images: makes it much harder to copy/paste your code into an answer.

Comment: yes i am trying to concatenate two string's entities. yes i am sure that imagePrefix and imageSuffix arrays are strings. i am doing the concatenate part correct but i need to get rid of these parantheses and quotes in the second image.

and thanks for note!

Comment: the objects in those arrays are arrays themselves. `(\n    ".png"\n)` is the way NSLog prints an NSArray that contains the NSString ".png".